# Convex Hull vs Convex Polygon and how to calculate it?

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, polygons

I was given some points to calculate the convex hull. So when I try to find that on internet I also saw that a question which has asked what is the difference of convex hull and convex polygon. 
According to my knowledge convex hull is the set of points in convex set and polygon is the representation of them in 2D plane. (PLEASE CORRECT ME IF IM WRONG)

However my given points are below and how I tried do calculate convex hull is given below.

**Points**

$P1=(1,1) , P2=(2,2)$ , $P3=(1.5,3)$ , $P4=(2.5,5)$ , $P5=(3,4)$, $P6=(3,2)$ , $P7=(5,4)$ , $P8=(6,2)$ , $P9=(4,1)$

**Tried way**

By plotting them in 2D space and going to each point, tried to draw lines to each remaining points and tried to find the internal angle less than 180 while being the largest one among other angles.

**Problem**

I'm not 100% sure that my method is correct. So if someone can please tell me how to find the convex hull by hand (not with programs) and tell me the difference between convex hull and polygon (if my interpretation is wrong).

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The convex hull of a subset $S$ of the plane is the smallest convex set that contains all of them.  If $S$ is finite, this is a convex polygon whose vertices form some subset of $S$.

In your case, the points look like

[image]

Start from, say, the highest point $P_4$, which must be one of the vertices of the convex hull (it wouldn't be in the convex hull of lower points).  Think of a line through $P_4$ that starts out horizontal and pivots clockwise.  The first point it hits will be $P_7$, so that's the next point of your polygon.

[image]

Draw the line segment $P_4, P_7$.  This will be an edge of your polygon.
Now pivot the line, still clockwise, around $P_7$.  The next point it hits will be $P_8$.

[image]

Draw the segment $P_7, P_8$, and continue in this way
until you come back to $P_4$.
And there's your convex hull.

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot for images and great clarification. So convex polygon is the representation and hull is the smallest set that has every point in it? Is that right? Also is there any wrong with the way I explained in question? Thank you

Comment: A convex polygon is a polygon that is a convex set.  The convex hull is the smallest **convex** set that has all your points in it.

Answer (score 2):

Start with a line parallel to the $x$ axis and far enough up so that all the points are below it. Then imagine that line dropping until it touches one (or maybe more) of the points. That will be the "highest" point $P=P4$. Now pivot that line around $P$ until it meets another point, say $Q$. Then $PQ$ is one of the edges of the polygon that is the boundary of the convex hull. Now pivot around $Q$ to find the next point $R$, and so on until you get back to $P$.

If I had time I'd draw the picture. Maybe someone will edit this and to that. In any case you should.

Comment: Thank you. Before more questions about that could you please tell me what I described about convex hull and polygon is right or wrong?

Comment: This is called the [Gift Wrapping Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm) in the literature. There's a nice illustration on the page of an algorithm running, but Ethan's method of doing this by hand is just fine. As for the difference between "Convex Hull" and "Convex Polygon": A convex hull is a type of convex polygon, but we usually refer to "hulls" when we work with a set of points and "polygon" when we work with the shape per-se.

Comment: The polygon is the boundary of the convex hull. Both are sets of points in the plane.

Comment: Thanks alot. But can you explain it a little bit more? What does that mean convex hull is a type of convex polygon?

Comment: @LarryB. I didn't think my algorithm was new - now I know it has a name. Thanks. I don't think a convex hull is a type of convex polygon, since the hull includes the interior. A convex polygon together with its interior is a kind of convex set.

Comment: @EthanBolker It sometimes is confusing when I read stuff about polygons, because some authors use the boundary-only definition, while others include the interior. I don't know of any standard across literature regarding polygons, let alone convex hulls. When I use the term convex hull, there's the possibility of a set of points related to the hull that don't all lie on the boundary. With a convex polygon, all the points related to the polygon are on the boundary.